# Best practice to synchronize button states

Tags: ios5, uibutton, state

I would like to know if there is some recommended way to synchronize some buttons states in ios. For example I have 5 buttons that i want to use as a filter on my data - they should all work in sync. So when one is selected i want the other other ones unselected. I could simply unselect all buttons and reselect only the one i want each time i select a button. Is there a better way to achieve this? I was thinking to take a look to the `Key Value Observing` mechanism too but any advice is very welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

One answer given by GeneralMike to a different [question on deselecting all buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315253/ios-table-view-how-to-deselect-all-buttons-in-all-cells) 
was to use UISegmentedControl or UISwitches.  While that was a different situation, it might be plausible for your requirements.